# Can the current date be inserted into output through XSLT v1.0

Tags: xslt, date

I have an incoming data stream that is being converted with XSLT v1.0
that incoming data does not contain any date information.
what i would like, is a nice way of getting the current date to become part of the resulting output stream.

I am aware of the 2.0 current-date() type functions - unfortunately those are not available to this environment...

any thoughts/hacks/alternatives?

tia

Comment: What platform? What programming language?

Comment: Good Question! (+1). See my answer for a solution which doesn't require the use of any extension functions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extension functions can be avoided.**

**Just pass the current date as one of the parameters to the XSLT transformation when initiating it**.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use:
http://exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/index.html

Date and time extension functions, implemented in some xslt processors, see referenced page for more info.

**Edit**
Another solution might be to pass the current datetime as a parameter to the xslt processor.